# MS Word 2007: RTL and LTR languages mix makes double space

Tags: microsoft-word, right-to-left

I have an RTL document, with English comments inside the text. If a line breaks in the middle of the English comment, the last RTL space before the comment and the last LTR space of the comment itself are viewd next to each other.

Is there a way to fix it? Is it fixed in newer versions of MS Word?

I'm having a problem to make myself clear, so here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0cou.png) of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have one space in RTL and one space in LTR. Do both in RTL.

I.e. whenever I insert English in RTL text, I type the RTL word after where the LTR is going to go. I make sure there are two spaces in the place where the LTR needs to go. Only then do I change language and change to LTR, and with the cursor between those two spaces, I then type the English text with no spaces.

This should solve your problem (assuming I understood it correctly)